# WP7 - Detect incoming text message

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

In the game I'm writing, it's really annoying to have the SMS popup during the game when a new message is received.

Is there anyway to detect an incoming SMS message so I can pause the game while the user takes care of the popup?

It's written in XNA.

Answer (score 2):

In `Silverlight` you can use [Obscured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured%28VS.92%29.aspx) and `Unobscured` events to listen that something is above your application (SMS, notification, alarm, etc.). I thing that in XNA you have the same:

```
public App()
{            
    RootFrame.Obscured += Obscured;
    RootFrame.Unobscured += Unobscured;
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however this doesn't work. I've done some more reading and most sites say it should call the deactivate event on text message - which it doesn't actively do (I tested it).